# KeyError: 'docker' error when running 'molecule create' command

Tags: ansible, molecule

I am new to using Molecule and I'm having an issue trying to simply 'create' the docker image.  The only files I have chanced within the molecule folder structure is 'molecule.yml', as seen below.

I have tried to re-setup molecule on multiple systems (mac/Ubuntu) but have encountered the same issue.  Just to get going I just want to get the 'create' working and that would be great!

molecule.yml

```
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: docker
lint:
  name: yamllint
platforms:
  - name: instance
    image: centos:7
    pre_build_image: true
provisioner:
  name: ansible
verifier:
  name: ansible
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/molecule", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/molecule/command/reset.py", line 46, in reset
    base.execute_cmdline_scenarios(scenario_name, args, command_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/molecule/command/base.py", line 94, in execute_cmdline_scenarios
    get_configs(args, command_args, ansible_args, glob_str),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/molecule/command/base.py", line 185, in get_configs
    configs = [
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/molecule/command/base.py", line 186, in <listcomp>
    config.Config(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/molecule/config.py", line 64, in __call__
    obj.after_init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/molecule/config.py", line 116, in after_init
    self.config = self._reget_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/molecule/config.py", line 308, in _reget_config
    env = util.merge_dicts(os.environ, self.env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/molecule/config.py", line 201, in env
    "MOLECULE_INSTANCE_CONFIG": self.driver.instance_config,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/functools.py", line 981, in __get__
    val = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/molecule/config.py", line 185, in driver
    driver = api.drivers(config=self)[driver_name]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/molecule/api.py", line 29, in __getitem__
    return self.__dict__[i]
KeyError: 'docker'
```

Comment: This can happen if Docker is not properly installed or configured on the system Ensure that Docker is installed and running on your system, and that Molecule is properly configured to use the Docker driver in the molecule.yml file.

Comment: I verified docker is enable and up and running and the docker driver is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to setup molecule on my system from scratch. After I had created a test role and changed the driver from `delegated` to `docker`, I got the exact same error as you.

I referred [this doc](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/installation/#install). Looks like, I was missing the, `molecule` plugin for `docker`. I installed that, using the command below command.

```
python3 -m pip install --user "molecule-plugins[docker]"
```

After that, the error has gone away. Can you please give it a try, if you haven't already?

Comment: wow...that fixed it!!!  I spend hours on trying to fix that issue.  Thanks so much phani raj goutham!